# Hexadecimal convertion error in python

Tags: python, hex

I need to make calculations with long hexadecimal number so I want to convert it to integer but, firstly, I try to remove spaces and EOL characters. But when I try conversion I get an error: "invalid literal for int() with base 16". Here is the code:

```
p = """670C354E 4ABC9804 F1746C08 CA18217C 32905E46 2E36CE3B
E39E772C 180E8603 9B2783A2 EC07A28F B5C55DF0 6F4C52C9
DE2BCBF6 95581718 3995497C EA956AE5 15D22618 98FA0510
15728E5A 8AAAC42D AD33170D 04507A33 A85521AB DF1CBA64
ECFB8504 58DBEF0A 8AEA7157 5D060C7D B3970F85 A6E1E4C7
ABF5AE8C DB0933D7 1E8C94E0 4A25619D CEE3D226 1AD2EE6B
F12FFA06 D98A0864 D8760273 3EC86A64 521F2B18 177B200C
BBE11757 7A615D6C 770988C0 BAD946E2 08E24FA0 74E5AB31""" 

pps = hex(int(p, 16))
print pps
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you want

```
pps = int(''.join(p.split()), 16)
```

Answer (score 3):

Remove the whitespace first. You can for example do this using `re.sub`:

```
p = re.sub(r'\s', '', p)
```

See it working online: [ideone](http://ideone.com/uTjYI)

Answer (score 2):

```
pps = hex(int(p.translate(None,' \n'),16))
```